# How do I send data from a form select element?

Tags: jquery

How can I choose an option from a `<select>` element and then send that value to MySQL? After that, I want a "save" button to be clicked programmatically.

**HTML :**

```
<body>
<form>
<select name="ABCD">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="D">C</option>
<option value="c">D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
</body>
```

**jQuery :**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "ABC.php",
  data:{ABCD:'B'},
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(data){

   $(data).find("form").find("input[type=submit]").click();
  }
});
</script>
```

I tried this:

```
data:{ABCD:'B'} //json
```

It did press on the save button, but it did not send data to MySQL.

How can I both send the selected value and click on the save button?

Comment: Javascript does'nt have direct access to MySQL, you'll need some serverside code for that ?

Comment: I know how I can send data to mysql by <input type='text' name='A' /> but i want <select></select> how ??!!

Comment: I think OP means he does not know how to retrieve the selected option of a `<select>` element in order to send that to the backend. However the "then click it" part is not clear to me.

Comment: @user2221553: There is NO "save" button in your example markup. Does ABC.php return HTML to be inserted in your page? Please make clear what do you want to "click" on.

Comment: `$(data).find("form").find("input[type=submit]").click();` probably you wanted to trigger click submit when you selected one from your selection. Use `$("input[type=submit]").trigger('click');` instead

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to send data when you choose from the selection.

```
<body>
<form>
<select name="ABCD" onchange="yourFunction(this.value)">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="D">C</option>
<option value="c">D</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>


<script>
function yourFunction(val){
    $.ajax({
      url: "ABC.php",
      data:{ABCD:val},
      datatype: "html",
      success: function(data){
        $(data).find("form input[type=submit]").trigger('click');
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

**or**

```
<form>
<select id="ABCD" name="ABCD">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="D">C</option>
<option value="c">D</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>

<script>
$('#ABCD').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "ABC.php",
      data:{ABCD:val},
      datatype: "html",
      success: function(data){
       $(data).find("form input[type=submit]").trigger('click');
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: **HTML :**

    <body>
    <form>
    <select name="ABCD">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="D">C</option>
    <option value="c">D</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
    </body>

**jQuery :**

    <script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "ABC.php",
      data:{ABCD:'B'},
      datatype: "html",
      success: function(data){
    
       $(data).find("form").find("input[type=submit]").click();
      }
      });
     </script>

Comment: @user2221553 Sorry, can you comment with a plain text?